# How to use directive that sits in a different module

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-module

```js
angular.module('mod1', [])
  .directive('myDir', ($timeout) => {
    return {
      ///....
    }
  });

angular.module('myApp', ['mod1'])
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>
  <my-dir valu='blablabla' />
</body>

</html>
```

So why this wouldn't work?
and say Unknown provider: `$compileProvider`,

but if I move directive into `myApp` module it works

Comment: Are you trying to use the $compile service somewhere in your directive?  If so, you need to inject it (like you do with $timeout).

Comment: but no if I move it into myApp module it works

Comment: Can you post a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: @Agzam, something must be going on somewhere else in your code, because I've [created a fiddle just like your code above](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/ZqFHp/) and it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it should work fine as long as module dependency has been provided correctly !!

Check this out : http://plnkr.co/edit/Wvb7melvMOgXh3FyoVnx?p=preview